# How to shuffle images to use for training and testing

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I would like to split a dataset of images into two, training and testing, sets. I would like to split the data 80/20 between training and testing. I need to take the 80% from all of the classes of images and I need to take the remaining 20% of images from all of the classes of images as well.

This is currently how I am splitting the data into two, but it does not work properly.

```
image_filenames = glob.glob("./imagenet-dogs/n02*/*.jpg")

image_filenames[0:2]

training_dataset = defaultdict(list)
testing_dataset = defaultdict(list)

image_filename_with_breed = map(lambda filename: (filename.split("/")[2], filename), image_filenames)

for dog_breed, breed_images in groupby(image_filename_with_breed, lambda x: x[0]):
    """
    Append training/testing image datasets to respective dictionaries
    """
    # Enumerate each breed's image and send ~20% of the images to a testing set
    for i, breed_image in enumerate(breed_images):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            testing_dataset[dog_breed].append(breed_image[1])
        else:
            training_dataset[dog_breed].append(breed_image[1])
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to do this to ensure that images are taken from all classes?

Would shuffling the images then taking 80%, appending it to training then taking the remaining 20% and appending it to testing work? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. scikit-learn is the de facto library for ML utilities in Python. It has, for instance, `train_test_split_` built in.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what **stratified train test split** does, implemented for example in sklearn:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html

The general idea is very simple:

1. For each class C:

   - take all samples belonging to class C
   - shuffle them (just in case)
   - take first K% to train, remaining to test
2. Shuffle train and test again (separately)

This way you have a guarantee of selecting proper ratio of each class (hence the word stratified).